# Python script utf-8 issue

Tags: python, utf-8

I try to use this [python text-to-speech converter](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS) to convert Greek into mp3.
Git says utf-8 is supported but when I try to translate text like "Γεια σου" it throws an error as shown below:

What I type on cmd: `gtts-cli.py "Γεια σου" -l el -o hi.mp3`
What I get:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 0: ordinal not in
>   range(128)

Any ideas?

Update:

I added utf-8 support as shown below. I even updated to python3. Still getting a similar error...

> 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

What I added:

```
text = args.text.decode('utf-8')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try: u"Γεια σου"

Comment: Also, add quoation marks around "el": gtts-cli.py "Γεια σου" -l "el" -o hi.mp3

Comment: None of these worked. Same error :/

Comment: Try to run your script in python3. It usually solve this kind of issues, assuming of course your script is python3 compatible. If it doesn't work, then you probably need to `decode()` / `encode()` your inputs/outputs in your script. This can be easier to say than to do though.

Answer (score 1):

There is [related open issue](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/76) in this project, please take a look.
Looks like [the fix](https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/pull/78/commits/8c632950cbc581d370b809e36f132c9f4c7538e1) was created by the somebody already though, but it is still not merged.

Comment: Alright, I added the commit to my files. I even updated to python3. Still getting a similar error... 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0:  invalid continuation byte

Comment: Do you run modified version or just the same command as previously? If you installed gTTS via pip, you could be using unpatched version